# Proving $\left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor a/b \right\rfloor}{c} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{a}{bc}\right\rfloor$ for positive integer $a$, $b$, $c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> How can we prove the following?
> $$\left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \dfrac{a}{b} \right\rfloor}{c} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{bc} \right\rfloor$$
> for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

I don’t know if I’m doing something wrong, but I can’t prove it even though I’m pretty sure it’s true.

Obviously, because the concept of algebra isn’t aware of the fact that we are restricting the variables to positive integers, and given my assumption that the equality doesn’t necessarily hold for non-integers, an element of non-algebraic problem solving is needed, i.e. making a change to the expression given our knowledge of that condition, which then allows for algebraic maneuvers that show that the equality holds. I think that’s what I’m missing.

Thanks.

Comment: For a lot of floor identities including yours, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155068/i-cant-seem-to-prove-propositions-involving-floor-ceiling-function-and-the-like/4156205#4156205) and read the section "A remarkable result" and the corollaries that follow. Since I put that post up for the purpose of being a canonical duplicate, I will let others decide if it's worth a shout or not.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use descriptive titles.  "How can we prove the following?" tells nothing about the subject of the question. It's a useless title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof for $\left\lfloor\frac 1j\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac n{jk}\right\rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338558/proof-for-left-lfloor-frac-1j-left-lfloor-frac-nk-right-rfloor-right-rfloor-l). Of course, the numerator is shown a bit differently and the variables are different, but otherwise it's the same.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I took a quick look at your post and it's very good as a canonical duplicate for these types of questions. However, there's actually a specific duplicate of this question which I just posted above. Also, FYI to you and the OP, this particular equality is given as the first result in Wikipedia's [Nested Divisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Nested_divisions) section.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for finding the good duplicate as well!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Write remainder theorem: $$a = bc\cdot k+r$$ where $0\leq r<bc$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a/b = \lfloor a/b \rfloor + \{a/b\} \implies$$
$$\frac{a/b}c = \frac{\lfloor a/b \rfloor}c+ \frac{\{a/b\}}c = \left \lfloor \frac{\lfloor a/b \rfloor}c\right \rfloor + \left  \{\frac{\lfloor a/b \rfloor}c\right\}+  \frac{\{a/b\}}c $$

So to finish we can prove that for any $q \in \mathbf{Q}^+$ and $p \in \mathbf{Z}^+$ we have

$$ \left \{\frac{\lfloor q \rfloor}p\right \}+  \frac{\{q\}}p < 1 \iff \left\{\frac{np+r}p\right\}+  \frac{\{q\}}p =\frac{r}p +  \frac{\{q\}}p  < 1$$

where $0 \leq r < p$, but $\frac{\{q\}}p  < \frac{1}{p}$ and we are done.